# Jquery mobile radio buttons unreponsive

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I have a simple control group for a radio button input as follows:

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="addUser" data-title="Add New User">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<h1>Add New User</h1>
</div>        
<div data-role="content">            
<div id="addNewUserErrMsg"></div>
<form name="addNewUserForm" action="addnewuser.php">
<label for="nuEmail">Email Address</label>
<input type=text id="nuEmail" name="Email" autofocus="autofocus">
<fieldset data-role=controlgroup data-mini=true>
    <input type=radio id="1" value=1 name=radio1>
    <label for="1">1</label>
    <input type=radio id="2" value=2 name=radio1>
    <label for="2">2</label>
    <input type=radio id="3" value=3 name=radio1>
    <label for="3">3</label>
</fieldset>
<label for="firstName">First Name</label>
<input type=text id="nuFirstName" name="firstName">
<label for="nuLastName">Last Name</label>
<input type=text id="nuLastName" name="lastName">
<label for="nuPassword">Password</label>
<input type=password id="nuPassword" name="password">
<label for="nuRePassword">ReEnter Password</label>
<input type=password id="nuRePassword" name="rePassword">
<label for="nuCell">Cell Phone (for alerts)</label>
<input type=text id="nuCell" name="cell">
<input type="submit" value="Create User" data-inline="true" data-theme="a">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" href="#home">Cancel</a>
</form>       
</div><!-- /content -->           
</div><!-- /adduser -->
```

The problem is that I cannot select any of the buttons. It's as if they're all disabled. They appear to be displayed correctly (empty circle followed by text and all grouped nicely).

I am using jquerymobile 1.4-rc1. I have tried in both Chrome and FireFox.

**Update**: The radio button is being selected (and value passed as part of POST request), however, there is no visual indication of that on the screen. Just an empty circle. No errors in the apache error log. No errors that firebug displays either.

Comment: I tried it in a fiddle and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fv92t/  Perhaps you can edit the fiddle to make it reproduce your issue...  There must be other code on your page causing the problem.

Comment: This part of code work just fine, so problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @ezanker I have modified the question to include the entire page. The radio field was initially generated through Ajax from a DB table of user types. I reduced it to this simple control group and it still fails.

Comment: I too have used the code you have provided and it works for me.  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bowlinmaster/Tes54/

Comment: @DrewB. I noticed that the jsfiddle code you are using is using jquerymobile 1.3.0b. I am using version 1.4-RC1. Are you able to get it working with 1.4?

Comment: My fiddle uses 1.4 and I updated it to use a dialog that opens from a link: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fv92t/2/  It still works.  Perhaps it is your code that dynamically creates the list, can we see that code?

Comment: @ezanker The example above is the code that is running/failing, I no longer generate the radio control group on the fly.

Comment: Well, if you visit my fiddle it seems to work fine.  Can you see anything else different in your code?

Comment: @mlewis54, I must be missing something because the external resources on my fiddle say 1.4 rc1

Comment: @DrewB.@ezanker, Do you know if they use an icon for the circle? Perhaps there is some breakdown on my end with references to the images directory (although all the other Icons in other widgets work just fine). I looked through the JQM code but it's not immediately obvious.

Comment: i just noticed that many of the attributes in your code example are not in quotes e.g. name=radio1 instead of name="radio1", data-role=controlgroup instead of data-role="controlgroup", etc. It did not break the fiddle, but perhaps try correcting this and see if it makes a difference at your end...

Comment: @mlewis54 I believe it uses a sprite image to fill in the circle icon